# Combine Prometheus alert conditions with "or"?

Tags: prometheus

I know Prometheus supports `and` and `unless` in alert statements:
https://www.robustperception.io/combining-alert-conditions/

Is there support for `or`?  I want to write an alert that fires if a timeseries has crossed a threshold or is absent for a given period of time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, `or` is a Prometheus operator. See [the docs](https://prometheus.io/docs/querying/operators/#logical/set-binary-operators).

Comment: In hindsight, I can see how the article wasn't about special constructs in the alert rules but just about how to use already-present operators in alert rules.

Answer (score 1):

Prometheus supports `or` operation as already pointed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45017328/274937). The following query must be used for alerting when a time series `foo` exceeds the given `threshold` or if a time series `foo` is absent for the duration `d`:

```
foo > threshold or absent_over_time(foo[d])
```

See [absent_over_time() docs](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#absent_over_time). Note that the `absent_over_time()` doesn't work as expected, e.g. doesn't return non-empty result if there are multiple time series with `foo` name and only a single time series has no new samples during the duration `d`. Basically, it works as expected only if there is only a single matching time series.

Prometheus doesn't provide functionality for creating universal alerts, which could detect time series without new samples over the given duration across multiple matching time series. However, such function exists in [VictoriaMetrics](https://github.com/VictoriaMetrics/VictoriaMetrics/) - see [lag()](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#lag). For example, the following query alerts (e.g. returns non-empty result) for time series with `foo` name, which exceeded the given `threshold` or which didn't have new samples during the last 5 minutes, while they had at least a single sample during the last hour:

```
foo > threshold or lag(foo[1h]) > 5m
```